# A class containing int in different Bytes?

Tags: c++, int, bit, unions

I would like to come up with a `Record` class, which containing a `int` but it could be a `int64_t`, `int32_t`, `int16_t`, `int8_t`.
But I had problem, when I want to read data out of this `Record` object.

---

Assumption in our context:
We know which `int` we want to save.
We have to pay attention to the **performance** of `getValue()` such function and the **size** of such class or union.

I would try 3 implementation at in context (very dummies).
1.The first implementation:

```
class Record{
  int64_t value;
  unsigned int bytes; // number of bytes, in context 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 representing int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t

  int64_t getValue() { return value; }
  unsigned int getNumByte() { return bytes; }
}
```

I would try to call `getValue()` and `getNumByte()` then to cast the value to the correct type, like `if (getNumByte() == 1)   auto value = (int8_t getValue())`.

---

2.Second: Using a `template`.

```
template <class T> 
class Record{
  T value;
  T getValue() { return value; }
}
```

---

3.Third: Using a `union`:

```
union Record {
  int64_t int64;
  int32_t int32;
  int16_t int16;
  int8_t int8;
};
```

---

My question:
Regarding this context, which implementation is better?
When they are all not so optimal, which approach would you come up with?

---

The **reason** for this question: It was a `Record` for `char*`. So in this situation would a `char* value` with a `unsigned int length` make sense. I want to switch to a `int` situation and have this problem.

Comment: It depends on the real problem you want to solve. At first glance, I would suggest to simply always use `int64_t`.

Comment: I'm really missing the point as to why the template does not fit your needs of usability and 'speed'.

Comment: Use the template if you know your type upfront. If you don't know the type, you should use a mixture of 1 + 3.

Comment: But then again, what is the benefit of using `Record<int64_t>` or `Record<int32_t>` as opposed to using `int64_t` and `int32_t` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is optimal in the sense that it will always be the same size as the underlying type, and will be optimized away. A few small changes.

```
template <class T> 
class Record {
    T value;
  public:
    const T& getValue() const { return value; }
}
```

However this solution does not allow you to have a container of Records with different template arguments, and makes serialization/deserialization code harder to work with.

Furthermore, if this code works for you, then ask yourself what purpose this "Record" serves? I would just use the underlying type itself.

Comment: Then why not optimize this away in the code and use directly the type T instead of the template?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Without context in the question there is no clear reason to create an abstraction in the first place.

Comment: @cdiggins Thanks. But you mean serialization/deserialization **for single Record**? Why it is harder to work with?